# Issue with Capturing photo using AVFoundation without flash and with Flash

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, image-capture

I'm trying to capture image using avfoundation framework without Flash and with Flash but i could not capture original image instead gives me black colour image while capturing it without Flash.

With the same code i can capture an image with lighting mode with Auto Flash, In that case i can able to see only part of image which has full light but not actual image.

I've set flashmode to AVCaptureFlashModeAuto.

Even with AVCaptureFlashModeOn captured image shows darker as compared to the original preview.

Help me to get it solved as i'm not able to find any solution.

Thanks.